# Why is this a sentence with a quantifier an open sentence?

Tags: logic, definition

From these notes on [Relational Logic](http://logic.stanford.edu/classes/cs157/2009/notes/chap06.html), the following two sentences are given as examples of 1) *open* and 2) *closed* sentences. The definition of an *open sentence* is one with **at least** *free variables*.

Isn't $x$ bound in (1)?

\begin{align}
1) & \qquad p(y) \Rightarrow \exists x.q(x,y) \\ 
2) & \forall y.( p(y) \Rightarrow \exists x.q(x,y) )
\end{align}

**Update:** Updated my question to reflect the answers. An open sentence must have *at least one* free variable, not *only* free variables.

Thanks everyone for your quick responses.

Thank you.

Comment: No, the definition of an _open sentence_ is one that contains at least one _free variable_.

Comment: @Student: the usual term is "quantifier", not "qualifier"

Comment: @CarlMummert: I misplaced the parentheses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An **open** "sentence" is one with **at least one** free variable: (with the occurrence of a variable which is not bound, it is not a "sentence" at all, but a **formula**). So in: $$(1) \quad p({\bf y}) \implies \exists x.q(x, {\bf y})$$

...while it is true that $x$ occurs strictly as a bounded variable, $\;\bf y$ is an *unbounded* variable, so the formula is *open*, since $y$ occurs unbound (twice).

**ADDED for clarification:**

From you link you have included, the following definition is written:

> "A sentence is open if and only if it has free variables. Otherwise, it is closed."

The *if and only if* connective applies to the existence of one or more free variables. That is, is should be read as

> "A sentence is open if and only if it has **any** free variable(s). Otherwise it is closed".

...or ...

> "A sentence is open if and only it has **one or more** free variables. Otherwise it is closed."

And so is **not meant to say**: "A sentence is open if and only if it has [only] free variables."

Comment: Thanks amWhy, as you pointed out, I misread the definition.

Comment: You're welcome, Student. We've all been there! (I for one, have had my share of misreading questions posted at Math.SE!)

Comment: @amWhy: Such a clean explanation ... TU! +1

Answer (score 6):

A formula is open if there is a variable with at least one free occurrence in the formula. A formula is closed if it is not open: if there is no free occurrence of any variable in the formula.

In formula (1) of the question, both occurrences of $y$ are free occurences.

Closed formulas are important because each of them is true or false in each first-order structure. An open formula, on the other hand, is only true or false relative to a variable assignment, and the truth value can differ for different variable assignments.